# Server Sent Events - Targeting response to specific clients

Tags: html

Using server sent events is fairly straight forward when all clients have to receive updates with the same data. For example updating the HTML clients on stock prices.

How can I target the response to different clients.

For example:

Client A needs to be notified on events that only interest client A (i.e. a new email has arrived for client A).

Client B doesn't need to be updated when client A receives an email.

Answer (score 1):

You can send parameter to the server for each client, for example:

```
var source = new EventSource('event.php?client=a');
```

Then in **event.php** you can output updates conditionally:

```
if(isset($_GET['client']) && $_GET['client'] == 'a'){
//show update for client a
}
```

Comment: what about if i have 2000 client.

Comment: Hi, I think the commented part `//show update for client a` is the part that contains the answer but unfortunately, it also happens to be the part that you have assumed to be trivial to the person who asked the question.